# Partial Derivative with Respect to Multiple Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If we take a multivariable function such as $w=f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$, I understand that we can take its partial derivative with respect to any one of its arguments, while the others stay unchanged. In this case, we can take the partial derivative with respect to $z$ as $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x,y,z)$. I also understand that we can take its total derivative which is with respect to all of its arguments, which can be expressed as $\frac{dt}{dw}f(x,y,z)$.

My question: how do we represent the derivative with respect to some but not all of a multivariable function's variables? How is this derivative classified? I am tempted to think it is partial but I am not sure since all of the definitions I have seen give it with respect to a single variable. Is it a "partial" total derivative?

Comment: Note: a total derivative would be something like $$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{dz}{dt}$$

Comment: See [mixed partial derivatives](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/HighOrderPartialDerivs.aspx)

Comment: Your notation with the "total derivative" makes absolutely no sense. I assume you mean $\frac d{dt} f(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ or, often, $\frac d{dt} f(t,x(t),y(t),z(t))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you mean is (for example), something like this $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}w$$

This is usually denoted by $$\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\partial y}$$and is defined by $$\lim_{\delta x\to 0}\lim_{\delta y \to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y,z)-f(x+\delta x,y,z)-f(x,y+\delta y,z)+f(x,y,z)}{\delta x\delta y}\right)$$

As an example, if we let $f(x,y,z)=x^2y^3$, then $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(x^2y^3)=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(3x^2y^2)=6xy^2$$

Comment: $f(x+\delta x,y,z)$ appears twice inside the limit, did you mean for one of them to be $f(x,y+\delta y,z)$ ?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding this limit definition anywhere else. Every example I can find of the partial derivative limit definition assumes you only have a delta for one variable at a time. Where can I read more about this?

Comment: @JosephGarvin yes you're right

Comment: It comes from this: Let $$g(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{f(x+\delta x,y,z)-f(x,y,z)}{\delta x}$$ Then $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}=\lim_{\delta y\to 0}\frac{g(x,y+\delta y,z)-g(x,y,z)}{\delta y}\\=\lim_{\delta y\to0}\frac{1}{\delta y}\lim_{\delta x\to0}\left(\frac{f(x+\delta x, y+\delta y,z)-f(x,y+\delta y,z)}{\delta x} - \frac{f(x+\delta x,y,z)-f(x,y,z)}{\delta x}\right)\\=\lim_{\delta x\to 0}\lim_{\delta y \to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+\delta x,y+\delta y,z)-f(x+\delta x,y,z)-f(x,y+\delta y,z)+f(x,y,z)}{\delta x\delta y}\right)$$